# How would I append a string onto a function like this?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn about functional programming and lambdas in JavaScript and the example I'm following indicates that exclamation points should be added. I got as far as creating the lambda, but trying to append has me stumped. The way I eventually did it is kind of hacky and looks wrong.

[Link to code example](http://jsbin.com/guwiji/edit?html,js,output) (not mine, but assigner's)

**Assigner's part**

```
var addToDom = (str) =>  
   document.getElementById('mydiv2').innerHTML = str;

var h1 = (str) => '<h1>' + str + '</h1>';

var echo = (str) => () => str;
```

**My addition**

```
String.prototype.repeat = function(times) {
   return (new Array(times + 1)).join(this);
};
var repeat = (str, multip) => str.repeat(multip);

R.compose(addToDom, h1, echo('Hello FP'.concat(repeat('!', 3))))();
```

**How you're supposed to create everything**

```
R.compose(addToDom, h1, repeat, echo('Hello FP'))();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exercise is a bit misleading, because a function that can "repeat a character any number of times" and the way he calls that one is a bit weird.

I'm guessing that you should create a function `repeatChar` that repeats a character any desired number of times and then use `repeat` to append "!" three times like this:

```
var repeatChar = (c,t) => Array(t+1).join(c)
var repeat = (str) => str + repeatChar('!', 3);

R.compose(addToDom, h1, repeat, echo('Hello FPx'))();
```

The `repeatChar` function takes the character (`c`) and the amount of repetitions (`t`) and returns a string of `t` times `c`. So repeatChar('!', 3) will return "!!!".

The slightly strange `Array(t+1)` creates an empty array with `t+1` items. When we call `join(c)` on that, we'll end up with `t` times the character `c`... no loops involved :-)

Then, in `repeat` we'll use this helper function to take `str` and append those three exclamation marks.

I guess, that's it then?

Comment: So there was a way. This functional stuff is difficult for me to understand, so thank you for explaining what you did.